# AdMob ads not loading suddenly after upgrading dependency version to 17.1.2

Tags: android, admob

I have followed the official documentation but ads are not loading. I am not sure about the reason, recently I just updated Google AdMob library dependency version to: **play-services-ads:17.1.2**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
```

Now getting the following errors in logcat when the application tries to load ad:

```
2018-12-18 18:04:28.943 17372-17387/? W/Ads: Got on activity created
2018-12-18 18:04:29.032 17372-17372/? D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl
2018-12-18 18:04:29.034 17372-17390/? I/Ads: App measurement is starting up, version: 13001
2018-12-18 18:04:29.034 17372-17390/? I/Ads: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2018-12-18 18:04:29.115 17372-17372/? I/Ads: Updating ad debug logging enablement.
2018-12-18 18:04:29.522 17372-17372/? I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("77F7E3A565B98A8D3C5B4E341A1D1AF2") to get test ads on this device.
2018-12-18 18:04:29.728 17372-17451/? W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
2018-12-18 18:04:29.728 17372-17451/? W/Ads: The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
2018-12-18 18:04:29.825 17372-17396/? W/Ads: Update ad debug logging enablement as false
2018-12-18 18:04:30.165 17372-17445/? W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
2018-12-18 18:04:30.194 22607-16822/? W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
2018-12-18 18:04:30.252 22607-17504/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14799021.14300000.1
2018-12-18 18:04:31.507 17372-17372/? I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

Test ads are showing fine in real device and emulator. However, my app has nothing to do with GPS location, so I have not invoke runtime permissions for obtaining location updates.

Comment: One your application will live then after may be show ads

Comment: means? . I generated signed apk and upload to playstore ads not showing

Comment: after two days admob started automatically started to show ads in my case